# Modify navigation in 2013 site that has 2010 UI from client side

Tags: 2013, 2010, csom, jsom, global-navigation

I've been asked to use CSOM to modify the top (global) navigation of a 2013 site that uses the 2010 UI. Can I use the 2013 CSOM for this, or am I stuck with 2010? Or is there a better approach via JSOM?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the 2013 CSOM to edit the navigation in a SP 2013 site that used the 2010 UI. [This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/987078/Add-Update-Delete-nodes-from-QuickLaunch-Current-N) was very helpful although the site I worked on is hosted on-premise.